# L Hopital rule and side limits

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Today I was in the process of solving a side limit, to be precise this limit:
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{\ln(\sin(2x)))}{\ln(\sin(x))} $$
I was supposed to use L'hopital and found that the answer was $1$. However, this function is not differentiable at some interval $(0,a)$ so L'hopital hypothesis is not true here. Based on the fact that I was supposed to use the rule here I assume that it can be used here, but if that was the case then it must be true that:$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{\ln(\sin(2x)))}{\ln(\sin(x))} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}\dfrac{\ln(\sin(2x)))}{\ln(\sin(x))} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\ln(\sin(2x)))}{\ln(\sin(x))} = \dfrac{\dfrac{d}{dx}\ln(\sin(2x)))}{\dfrac{d}{dx}\ln(\sin(x))}$$
Because that is what I believe L'hopital states.

What is happening here? L'hopital should not be used here? Is it real that the rule may be true for JUST one side limit in case it is a limit point of the domain? Or even.. Is $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\ln(\sin(2x)))}{\ln(\sin(x))} = 1$$ ?

I am pretty confused with this fact about side limits and limit points of the domain, and now with L'hopital rule into play it is even more confusing. I hope that I expressed myself the best way possible.

Thanks for your time and sorry if there are grammar mistakes, I do not speak english.

Answer (score 1):

Why use L'Hopital's rule?  We have $$\sin 2x = 2\sin x \cos x,$$ and since in a sufficiently small neighborhood of $0$, we have $\cos x > 0$, it follows that $$\log \sin 2x = \log \sin x + \log (2 \cos x).$$  Then $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\log \sin 2x}{\log \sin x} = 1 + \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\log (2 \cos x)}{\log \sin x} = 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Write $\left(\ln(\sin(kx))\right)' = \dfrac{k\cos(kx)}{\sin(kx)}$,and plug in $k =1,2$ into the equation to get the derivatives and take it from there.